# Что не так с переменной d1 в определении её?

Tags: python

консоль ругается на тип данных, но она же должна привести к одному типу?разве нет?

```
import numpy as np
from math import *
Vxy = 3.71
Vxx = 7.51
Vpp = -8.13
Vss = 5.88
Vsp = 2.31
k = np.array([pi/4, pi/4, pi/4])  # k-- волновой вектор
E = 7.20
a = 5.4307 * 10**(-10) # a-- это постоянная решетки
i = -1
d1 = np.array([a/4, a/4, a/4])
d2 = np.array([a/4, -a/4, -a/4])
d3 = np.array([-a/4, -a/4, a/4])
d4 = np.array([-a/4, a/4, -a/4])
g1 = exp(1j * (k * d1) + 1j * (k * d3) + 1j * (k * d4))
g2 = exp(1j * (k * d1) + 1j * (k * d3) + 1j * (k * d4))
g3 = exp(1j * (k * d1) + 1j * (k * d3) + 1j * (k * d4))
g4 = exp(1j * (k * d1) + 1j * (k * d3) + 1j * (k * d4))
H = np.array([E, Vss * g1, 0, 0, 0, Vsp * g2, Vsp * g3, Vsp * g4],
             [Vss * (-g1), E, -Vsp * g2, -Vsp * g3, -Vsp * g4, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, -Vsp * g2, E, 0, 0, Vxx * g1, Vxy * g4, Vxy * g3],
             [0, -Vsp * g3, 0, E, 0, Vxy * g4, Vxx * g1, Vxy * g2],
             [0, -Vsp * g4, 0, 0, E, Vxy * g3, Vxy * g2, Vxx * g1],
             [Vsp * (-g2), 0, Vxx * (-g1), Vxy * (-g4), Vxy * (-g3), E, 0, 0],
             [Vsp * (-g3), 0, Vxx * (-g4), Vxy * (-g1), Vxy * (-g2), 0, E, 0],
             [Vsp * (-g4), 0, Vxy * (-g3), Vxy * (-g2), Vxx * (-g1), 0, 0, E])
print(np.linalg.eig(H))
```

Comment: Лучше всегда при ошибке в коде выкладывайте стек ошибки

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, стек ошибки-- это, то что выводит консоль или как это?

Comment: Угу, типо: `>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`

Comment: @gil9red, понял))) теперь ругается на 22 строчку: там что-то с переменной g1 !(((  я перевел, но не понимаю в чем подвох: "только длина 1 множество может быть преобразована в скаляры Пайтона."

Comment: Так лучше, но не видно сообщение с ошибкой

Comment: @gil9red, вот сообщение:  g1 = exp(i * 1 * (k * d1) + i * 1 * (k * d3) + i *1 * (k * d4))

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Замените методы `math` на аналогичные методы из `np`, т.е. вместо `exp` используйте `np.exp`

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, а в чем разница? кстати pi подчеркивает среда, эту константу тоже можно с np.pi ?

Comment: У `np` свой тип, отличный от стандартного в питоне, с которым стандартный `exp` не умеет работать

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, теперь консоль выдает: " [Vsp * (-g4), 0, Vxy * (-g3), Vxy * (-g2), Vxx * (-g1), 0, 0, E]

ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted ". А библиотеку math можно убрать?(она лишняя?)

Comment: @gil9red, вот я перевел: " приняты только 2 аргумента неключевого слова "

Comment: math можно убрать. Это значит, что вы неправильно используете функцию `np.array`, у нее есть список аргументов/параметров: `def array(p_object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)`. кст, а должно быть в `[Vss * (-g1), E, -Vsp * g2, -Vsp * g3, -Vsp * g4, 0],` 6 элементов? Если смотреть на другие строки, то везде их по 8

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо,1.)  на счет параметров не очень понимаю, ведь я же спомощью этой функции делаю матрицу, разве у меня не то?(вот, что должно быть:  https://prnt.sc/grzp9p )    2.) и спасибо за число 6, я и в самом деле забыл там два нолика в конце добавить!)

Comment: Я numpy не знаю, но мне кажется, что для создания матриц нужно метод matrix использовать

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, а как бы с методом matrix можно сделать?

Comment: Не знаю, с numpy не работал, поищите в спецификации numpy примеры

Comment: @gil9red, я изменил на np.matrix и уже есть прогресс: консоль пишет--- [Vsp * (-g4), 0, Vxy * (-g3), Vxy * (-g2), Vxx * (-g1), 0, 0, E]
TypeError: __new__() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 9 were given

Comment: а вот перевод: "__ новый __ () берет от 2 до 4 позиционных аргументов, но 9 были даны".P.S.: пока еще пытаюсь разобраться с этим методом matrix((

Comment: думаю, что матрица это не набор списков `[...], [...], [...]`, а список списков, в котором каждый элемент главного списка это другие списки, которые являются его строками, т.е.: `[[...], [...], [...]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно исправить `a = 5,4307` на `a = 5.4307`

При `a = 5,4307` будет создан кортеж (`tuple`) с значением `(5, 4307)`